# Spring batch admin upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am working on a application to upgrade it to JAVA 8.

It is using spring integration, spring batch and spring batch admin.

For spring integration and spring batch to work on java 8, we have to upgrade it to latest spring integration which is 4.3.5 (this is what I'm trying to use) and spring batch to 3.0.7.

Problem I am facing is while upgrading SPRING BATCH ADMIN, which was last released in jan 2015 and internally it uses old spring integration version.

Wanted to ask- what are my options as application is very much depending on spring batch admin?

Is there any alternative for spring batch admin which can be used with spring integration 4.3.5 and spring batch 3.0.7.

Need advice and help regarding the same.

Note: I have read somewhere that I can use spring boot admin.

Please let me know if need more clarification on above question.
.

Comment: you could exclude the old dependencies that spring-batch-admin and use the new ones - and see if that works. search for `<exclude>` maven tags...

Comment: @eugene ; I tried using spring batch admin 1.3.1 , but no luck getting runtime error related to tags in XML used in that jars

Comment: What platform are you running this on (WebSphere, Tomcat, CloudFoundry, Kubernetes, etc)?

Comment: @MIchael : we are using weblogic

Comment: I ask because the *best* option is to migrate to Spring Cloud Data Flow...

Comment: I will have a look on this,. As batch admin is used for UI , so cloud data flow will work  with spring batch??

Comment: @Michael Minella : is thr any future release planned for spring batch admin update for java 8.

Comment: I would recommend looking at Spring Cloud Data Flow over Spring Batch Admin.

Comment: @MichaelMinella : whole application is in spring batch and for UI , batch admin.
whats is the possibilities with spring boot admin with spring batch and spring boot ? 

Please help with any other option if you have :(
I hope many people may have similar issue

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch Admin project is deprecated. There won't be 2.0.0 release.

Spring Cloud Data Flow isn't direct alternative to Spring Batch Admin. It is about orchestration of processes in cloud environment while Spring Batch Admin is a dashboard for `BATCH_` tables, though this functionality is present in Data Flow in its own way ))

**UPDATE** If you are in 2022, check this `de.codecentric:batch-web-spring-boot-starter`:

- https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-starter-batch-web
- https://blog.codecentric.de/batch-web-spring-boot-starter-2-0-1-released
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.codecentric/batch-web-spring-boot-starter

Answer (score 0):

This is a fork of spring-batch-admin that might be useful...

https://github.com/httpants/spring-batch-admin